# Django - Cannot add new models

Tags: python, django, django-models

Embrassing question.

I cannot seem to be able to add new models.

I have list of models in my models.py file which appear in admin panel.

However, the new model I am trying to add does not appear.

What makes it embarrassing is that it was showing earlier this afternoon.

I made some changes to the code and clearly something went wrong. I deleted the code, hoping this might resolve the problem, but no.

Just in case it would be related to the actual model I was creating, I completly change the code to something simple (see below) but again no change.

I am not too sure what I clicked, deleted to make this happen.

Any clues?

(PS: I did do the migrations.)
(PS2: there is post about user permission. Where the user didnt have the right level of permissions to see the models which is why the model couldnt be seen. In my case, Im logged in as the superuser so this problem shouldnt be relevant for me)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from decimal import Decimal
import locale
import logging
...    
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Venue Name', max_length=120)
    
    def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

##EDIT##
admin.py

```
from .models import Event
from django.urls import path
from django.shortcuts import render
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Event)
```

Comment: Have you registered the model in admin.py? Can you add that code if you have

Comment: any change in models you need to run makemigrations then migrate. and as Iain said register model in admin.py

Comment: Yes, the models were registered in the admin.py. (I added the code) and I did run the migrations. Out of despair, I downloaded an older version of the code from github which solved the problem. I am not too sure what I did wrong. (thanks for tying to help!)